# Singleton idiom in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

I want to transpile code from a custom language to C++. For the singleton pattern, I see at least 2 simple ways of doing the translation.

1:

```
namespace Singleton 
{
    int a, b; 
    int Function() 
    {
        return a+b; 
    }
}

int test = Singleton::Function();
```

2:

```
struct Singleton 
{
    int a, b; 
    int Function() 
    {
        return a+b; 
    }
} Singleton; //<-- The only instance

int test = Singleton.Function();
```

I know that conceptually these are equivalent. I'm not looking for encapsulation/safeguards against instancing/definition separation, and since this is transpilation I do no care about aesthetics or even code length.

But I want to know: will these always strictly generate the same assembly? I do tend to prefer the second one because in a struct I can declare methods that reference each other in any order I want:

```
struct Singleton 
{
    int a, b; 
    int Function2() 
    {
        return Function() + 1; 
    }
    int Function() 
    {
        return a+b; 
    }
} Singleton;

int test = Singleton.Function2();
```

Whereas if I use a namespace, Function() should be an undeclared identifier.

So, do I have any practical reason to ever transpile into a namespace? Will the single instance of a structure always or at all have the same meaning after the compiler is done?

Comment: Both of these "simple ways" just declare global variables 1) in namespace scope 2) in global scope. They have nothing to do with singletons.

Comment: BTW, it is not a singleton: you can create several instances of singleton.

Comment: Not sure why singleton is in the title because neither of these is one and you even said you didnt care about safeguards against instacing the class which is to my knowledge the point of singleton. Maybe you should re-focus the question on the differences between the 2 approaches and not mention singleton at all?

Comment: I'd say that your expressed preference for the struct version is valid and sufficient. Why are you worrying about the potential different compilation?

Comment: Your namespace Singleton will create multiple definitions (aka it will not link) of a and b and the functions if included into more than one translation unit. Your struct Singleton will do the same for Singleton.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have used the word Singleton then. Indeed ultimately all I want is a bunch of global variables and functions stored behind a word. When I say Singleton, I hear "something that will only exist once, in one place". The transpiler is obviously a coherent entity and does not need safeguards to prevent himself from making another instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They almost certainly will *not* generate the same assembly.  In the namespace case, `Function` takes zero arguments and accesses two global variables; in the `struct` case, `Function` takes a hidden `this` pointer and references two variables via that.

However it is vanishingly unlikely that the performance difference is going to matter, so whether the assembly is the same or not doesn't matter.

The real question is whether you want to share this singleton between two translation units (.cpp files).  If you do, I would mildly prefer the namespace version because the language guarantees there will only be one, whereas with the struct, you could accidently write `struct Singleton Singleton2;` and end up with two of them.

If the singleton is local to a single .CPP, then you don't need to name the struct:

```
struct // nameless struct.
{
    int a, b; 
    int Function() 
    {
        return a+b; 
    }
} Singleton; //<-- The only instance

int test = Singleton.Function();
```

Final thought:  There is another option (which is almost identical to the namespace option):

```
struct Singleton 
{
    static int a, b; // All members must be static.
    static int Function() 
    {
        return a+b; 
    }
    Singleton() = delete;  // Prevent creating any instances.
};
Singleton::a;  // Must define the static members.
Singleton::b;


int test = Singleton::Function();
```

This allows declaring the functions in an arbitrary order, and can be shared between files.

Comment: Nice answer. However my transpiler will not generate .cpp files, only headers. My only goal is to exploit modern C++ for compilation. I want to make a new language with slightly simpler rules. So separating definitions or avoiding typos is something I do not care about. The only concern is maximum performance. 



You say the struct will necessarily introduce overhead because of "this". But if there is only one instance, won't a reasonable compiler simply optimize the pointer away, because there is only one instance in one chunk of memory and that is known at compile time?

Comment: It is *very* hard for a compiler to spot that there is only one instance.  Also, why do you say "overhead"?  I said it would be different, but it is perfectly possible to imagine systems where the struct would be faster than the namespace (access to global variables can be slow, and the struct only has one global, whereas the namespace has two).  If you *really* care about performance: measure.

Comment: Only generating header files makes this much more tricky.  Unless you can guarantee that a single header file will only be included once (which *may* be possible for you), you have serious problems with multiple definitions of static variables.

Comment: I already code in C++ with headers only. I know, I'm an alien. Also I only use structures and namespaces, no encapsulation. Somehow it makes the code short and clean for my eyes and modern C++ is forced to be tolerant for everyone so it accepts it. That's why I want to make my own language layer on top of it, so that it's no longer heresy but actually a whole new thing.

Comment: I do not use the static word often. It's true it doesn't seem to work for variables. But why would I ever need a static variable? As shown above I have two other ways of achieving the same thing. This kind of mess is why I want to abstract away C++.

Comment: @demanze By "static" I meant "static storage duration".  The struct solution has a static variable called `Singleton`, and the namespace solution + my third solution both have static variables `Singleton::a` and `Singleton::b`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156068/discussion-between-martin-bonner-and-demanze).